# Item container scrolling when the screen height changes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, overflow

Here is the structure of my site [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-ovdjsc?file=/src/styles.css), it consist of a video player and settings part with list of some notifications. I need to add item container scrolling when the screen height changes. Only the container with class `PreviewWrapper` with the list of notifications should be able to scroll when the screen height changes. Could you help me resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Short tip. You need add a listener to check window resize and rerender screen so you achieve your goal

Comment: The code sandbox with the default react project, please add your code there.

Comment: sorry, I've changed the link, please https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-ovdjsc?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a fixed height for the `section bar` for example `200px` and make the `overflow: auto;`

```
.PreviewWrapper {
  padding: 0 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Also, you need to add `height: 100%` for the element has class `.AppWrapper` to take the full height of it's parent

```
.AppWrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}
```

**[CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-forked-1lczc0?file=/src/styles.css:61-110)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! But it's not working when I reduce the screen height.  Try to add to  .PreviewWrapper {
  padding: 0 2rem 2rem 2rem;
  display: block;
  height: 325px;
  overflow: auto;
}   and then try to resize screen height, scroll doesn't appear.

Comment: No, I want to have an ability to scroll items inside PreviewWrapper container. But this ability should appear just after height of screen decrease. For example, by default when we have 1000px height of screen we see all 3 items without scroll (we can render 3 items in this container maximum). But if we change height of screen to 600px we can see scroll at this container.